# How to add users in Office 365 and assign license using graph api

Tags: c#, .net, office365, exchange-server

We are working on a project where we need to add new users in Exchange online and assign them license programmatically using Microsoft graph api.

Is this possible if yes, then how can we solve this.

Comment: Get final solution in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to follow the two following documentation pages:

[Add User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Assign License](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-assignlicense?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

These pages show examples of how to handle this with C#.

You may do testing in Postman to ensure your authentication is working properly and you are using a correctly formatted body etc.

Comment: What are Guids: ***DisabledPlans and SkuId*** ? How-to get them?

Comment: Have a look at this page: [Licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference)
The SKUId is listed as a GUID in this page.
Service plans(Disabled Plans) are also listed

Comment: How-to get the number of available licenses?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
You will want to look at "ConsumedUnits" and "prepaidUnits"